# ROS Calibration Camera Problems

Tags: ros, cameras, calibration

I am trying to calibrate a monocular camera using ROS with the help of this website: [How to Calibrate a Monocular Camera](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration). When I run `rostopic list`, I get:

```
/left
/right
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/usb_cam/image
```

When I run `rosservice list`, I get:

```
/cameracalibrator/get_loggers
/cameracalibrator/set_logger_level
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level
```

Finally, when I run:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 10x7 --square 0.025 image:=/usb_cam/image camera:=/usb_cam
```

It says:

```
('Waiting for service', '/usb_cam/set_camera_info', '...')
Service not found
```

I even added the parameter at the end, `--no-service-check`, but that just makes the terminal stall indefinitely.

Could someone please help me figure out what is going wrong and how I can fix it? Also if it is important, `usb_cam` is saved at `catkin_ws/src/usb_cam`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem fixed, apparently my camera was not "on", and it only turned on after I ran the .launch test file right before I do the calibration. Also it should be image_raw, not image in the command.

Comment: In that case, it's perfectly fine to tag your own answer as "the good answer". It makes sure that the question gets marked as "answered" in the SE system.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the answer you seek may have already been [answered on the ROS website](http://answers.ros.org/question/62778/ros_camera_info-service-not-found-for-usb_cam/).

Specifically, a bug in the camera driver in that it is not advertising the proper service.

Comment: So how would I get around this bug? I'm sorry, I am very new to ROS.

Comment: So I ran the `roslaunch usb_cam-test.launch` command, and then ran the same command as above specified. This time after the Waiting message, it says OK and then stalls, with and without the parameter at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get around it.  My advice is to ask on that other forum, where people seem much more knowledgable on that particular topic.